# I am facing Issues after migrating Antlr version 3.1.1 to Antlr 3.3 (getting NoSuchMethodError: CommonTreeNodeStream.getNodeIndex)

Tags: antlr

Currently im using ANTLR V3.1.1,now i have migrated to ANTLR V3.3. after that i'm getting the following error:

> Unexpected exception occurred: 
>           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTreeNodeStream.getNodeIndex(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
>       at
>   ***.expression.antlr.FocusCommonTreeNodeStream.getNodeIndex(FocusCommonTreeNodeStream.java:16)

Please help me on this issue..
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that produces the exception in v3.3 but not in v3.1.1? Please make sure you understand what an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is before editing your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I presume you have generated new source files using the v3.3 `org.antlr.Tool` (and compiled them!)? Running v3.1.1 .class files with the v3.3 run-time files will cause problems, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have not generated class files using V3.3. I am directly replacing the V3.1 to V3.3 jar and start running. My question here is, In our source file we are using getNodeIndex(Obj) but this method is not at all available in V3.3 then why should we compile and generate the classes to run. Please clarify.

Comment: If you generate a lexer and parser with v3.1.1, these lexer and parser classes then rely on run-time classes available in the v3.1.1 JAR. You can't just swap the JAR files (including the run-time classes). But if you're not generating new Java source files (a new lexer and parser), then I see no need why you should upgrade to v3.3. Just keep v3.1.1.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a chance of performance improvement of the application if I upgrade my ANTLR version from 3.1.1 to 3.3.
Do you have any idea on this? Please let me know.

Comment: If you want to upgrade from v3.1.1 to v3.3, then you need to generate a new lexer and parser from your `.g` grammar file using ANTLR v.3.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Please clarify... can i get performance improvement only because of this ANTLR upgradation?

Comment: That is impossible to tell. You'll have to try and measure the difference.

Answer (score 0):

*Okay, by looking at the comments under your original post, I'll post the answer here for completeness sake, in case people find this Q&A after searching the web.*

---

The reason you get this exception is because you simply replaced the ANTLR jar and did *not* regenerate a lexer and parser from your grammar. The compiled lexer and parser files that were generated by ANTLR v3.1.1 need the ANTLR v3.1.1 run-time classes. They won't (necessarily) work with other ANTLR run-time versions.

So, if you want to upgrade to ANTLR v3.3, you'll need to re-generate a (new) lexer and parser from your grammar file using the `org.antlr.Tool` from ANTLR v3.3.